# Unable to query data for particular age range from a table in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a table with date-of-birth column and other columns. I want to extract all data for a particular age range (>25). I have written the following code but it's not working. It shows blank rows. I am using the format function because in my table the data is in 'dd-mm-yyyy' format.

My table is in MS Access and I have written the query in VBA.

```
select * from Customer 
where DOB > format(dateadd('yyyy', -25, date()), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: Format property setting does not change the actual data. Have you changed date format in computer settings? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: No. I haven't. It's in date type in Access.

Comment: If your computer Regional settings are set for U.S. style date, then don't Format the date in code. If users input dates in dd/mm/yyyy order, many values are likely not stored as the date you expect. Access will understand 13/1/2018 as 13Jan2018 and save correctly. However, Access will accept 1/2/2018 in that order but will read it as 2Jan2018, not 1Feb2018. Did you read the AllenBrowne article?

Comment: Yes, I read the article. My computer regional settings are in the same format as my database date, 'dd-mm-yyyy'. I have tried without the format function as well and it gives the same result.

Comment: Sorry, that's the limit of my understanding of International dates. I don't have to deal with the issue. Try formatting both the DOB field and the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Format is for display only, so:

```
select * from Customer 
where DOB > DateAdd('yyyy', -25, Date())
```